# Print statement attached to math.random not printing properly

Tags: if-statement, math, random, printing, lua

I am trying to create a program that will generate a random number between one and two, then print "Success!" or "Failure..." depending on the number.

Whenever I run the code, no matter which number I get, the  print statement always returns "Failure..."

This is my code:

```
print(math.random(1,2))

if math.random == 1
   then
    print("Success!")
   else
    print("Failure...")
   end
```

Comment: You're comparing the `math.random` function against a number. A function isn't a number, so this will always be `false`. You should use `math.random(1, 2) == 1` instead.

Answer (score 4):

you're trying to use math.random as a property instead of a function

```
local randomNumber = math.random(1, 2)

if randomNumber == 1 then
    print("Success!")
else
    print("Failure...")
end
```